# SQL Server filtering out string but leave empty strings

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with with details of my companies products, and one of the columns has categories for the products but also empty strings for products that have not yet been categorized.

I'm trying to filter out the category 'trash' and leave the rest including the empty ones, but when I apply the filter, the empty ones are disappearing too...
is this normal? how can I filter out the 'trash' and leave everything else including empty values?

I'm using a `WHERE` clause like this:

```
WHERE 
    table.month = 8 AND table.category <> 'trash'
```

Comment: Show us your data. I Guess the disappeared items have `NULL` values.

Comment: Are you sure that there *are* items for `month = 8` that have `category <> 'trash'`?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Nope, not in SQL Server as you can see here. https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/523606

Comment: You're both right, of course...

Comment: hi guys. Yes, I'm sure there are items for month = 8 that have category <> 'trash'. We have several other categories and a bunch of products without categories yet; and yes, these are NULL values.

Comment: @TedoG. Sorry, I got mixed up here. Had to bring the extended logic tables back to my mind... :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you have entries with `category` `NULL`. Thus, they will not be returned, because by definition the comparison `null <> 'trash'` is neither `true` nor `false`, but a `WHERE` clause will only return records where all conditions are `true`.

You could modify your statement to this:

```
WHERE table.month = 8 AND ISNULL(table.category, '') <> 'trash'
```

or this:

```
WHERE table.month = 8 AND (table.category is null OR table.category <> 'trash')
```

This former replaces `null` values with empty strings, which should return what you want.

Comment: thank you so much, the first statement worked perfectly. I had no idea that NULLs would behave like this. Thank you